# How to resize CSS images that serve as radio fields?

Tags: css

I'm not understanding how to resize the stars here http://jsfiddle.net/ghvNn/261/, as anytime I change a size or width attribute, it seems to remove the ability to click each star.  I also see more than 5 stars being rendered when I change the width.  My question is, which values do I need to change here in order to make the stars smaller and why are more than 5 stars shown when I change the size attributes?

```
<span class="star-rating">
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5"><i></i>
</span>


.star-rating {
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMjBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjAgMjAiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDIwIDIwIiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48cG9seWdvbiBmaWxsPSIjREREREREIiBwb2ludHM9IjEwLDAgMTMuMDksNi41ODMgMjAsNy42MzkgMTUsMTIuNzY0IDE2LjE4LDIwIDEwLDE2LjU4MyAzLjgyLDIwIDUsMTIuNzY0IDAsNy42MzkgNi45MSw2LjU4MyAiLz48L3N2Zz4=');
  background-size: contain;
}
.star-rating i {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMjBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjAgMjAiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDIwIDIwIiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48cG9seWdvbiBmaWxsPSIjRkZERjg4IiBwb2ludHM9IjEwLDAgMTMuMDksNi41ODMgMjAsNy42MzkgMTUsMTIuNzY0IDE2LjE4LDIwIDEwLDE2LjU4MyAzLjgyLDIwIDUsMTIuNzY0IDAsNy42MzkgNi45MSw2LjU4MyAiLz48L3N2Zz4=');
  background-size: contain;
}
.star-rating input {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
.star-rating input:hover + i,
.star-rating input:checked + i {
  opacity: 1;
}
.star-rating i ~ i {
  width: 40%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i {
  width: 60%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i ~ i {
  width: 80%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i {
  width: 100%;
}
::after,
::before {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The stars are simply a background image and so conform to the usual rules of any background image.

They have a `background-size` property of `contain` which is being used to size the stars to the height of the `.star-rating` element.

Adjusting the `height` of `.star-rating` will alter the size of the stars. Adjusting the width will alter the number of visible stars.

Halving the `width` and `height`of `star-rating` will halve the size of the stars and because your inputs have a height of `100%`and a width of `20%`, as long as five stars are visible, your inputs and stars will match up

[JSFiddle demo at half original size](http://jsfiddle.net/ghvNn/446/)

```css
.star-rating {
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 125px;
  height: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMjBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjAgMjAiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDIwIDIwIiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48cG9seWdvbiBmaWxsPSIjREREREREIiBwb2ludHM9IjEwLDAgMTMuMDksNi41ODMgMjAsNy42MzkgMTUsMTIuNzY0IDE2LjE4LDIwIDEwLDE2LjU4MyAzLjgyLDIwIDUsMTIuNzY0IDAsNy42MzkgNi45MSw2LjU4MyAiLz48L3N2Zz4=');
  background-size: contain;
}
.star-rating i {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMjBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjAgMjAiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDIwIDIwIiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48cG9seWdvbiBmaWxsPSIjRkZERjg4IiBwb2ludHM9IjEwLDAgMTMuMDksNi41ODMgMjAsNy42MzkgMTUsMTIuNzY0IDE2LjE4LDIwIDEwLDE2LjU4MyAzLjgyLDIwIDUsMTIuNzY0IDAsNy42MzkgNi45MSw2LjU4MyAiLz48L3N2Zz4=');
  background-size: contain;
}
.star-rating input {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
.star-rating input:hover + i,
.star-rating input:checked + i {
  opacity: 1;
}
.star-rating i ~ i {
  width: 40%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i {
  width: 60%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i ~ i {
  width: 80%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i {
  width: 100%;
}
::after,
::before {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<span class="star-rating">
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5"><i></i>
</span>
<br><br>
<span class="star-rating">      
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3"><i></i>
</span>
```